# Most optimal way to get all records IN previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

In the past I have always used:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(m, [DATE_COL], GETDATE()) = 1
```

which gets me ALL the record that occurred in the PREVIOUS month. For example if I ran this query, it will get me all records which occurred in January.

However I am currently working with a significantly bigger table and if I use the above query, it takes almost 30 minutes for it to load. However, if I use something like

```
WHERE [SettlementDate] >= DateAdd(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
```

it will usually run in under 10 seconds.

My question is:
How can I get the same result as `WHERE DATEDIFF(m, [DATE_COL], GETDATE()) = 1` without the crazy increase in processing time?

Thank you!

Comment: Try comparing `DATEPART(m, [date_col])` with the desired month.

Comment: This `DateAdd(DAY, -31, GETDATE())` may also evaluate to wrong data. As if  `GETDATE()` is March, 1st for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is slow because when you do `DATEDIFF(m, [DATE_COL], GETDATE())` it can not use any indexes on the `[Date_Col]`.

Anyway you can use the following where clause, this will use indexes on the `[SettlementDate]` and hopefully it should perform a lot better than the `DATEDIFF()` function.

```
WHERE [SettlementDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)  
AND [SettlementDate]  < DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a function call and the query optimizer cannot see inside functions. That means, it cannot decide if use an index or not. In that case it reads the whole table that can take very long time.
I suggest you to use variables and I believe your query will get better result:

```
declare @From datetime -- choose the same type as your SettlementDate column
set @From = DateAdd(DAY, -31, GETDATE()) -- compute the starting date
select * from yourTable where SettlementDate >= @From
```

In that case the sql server will know that you want to compare your SettlementDate value with a date and there is nothing other that has to compute. If you have index in that column, it will use that.

Additional information about SARGable queries: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827764/Sargable-query-in-SQL-server